# Netbeans: Is it possible to install mulltiple Netbeans for each different development need?

Tags: netbeans

I am using Netbeans for various development needs. But installing lots of plugin makes Netbeans very slow. Is it possible to have multiple Netbeans installation for each specific development need like Eclipse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an other way of having multiple Netbeans for different development needs. By using this method you do not have to have multiple installations or archived versions of the Netbeans. The only thing you have to do is provide a different user directory for each development profile. Here ara the steps:

- Create a new folder for your new development profile. For example "Netbeans for PHP".
- Create a new short cut for your new profile.
- Add following paramater to short cut: `--userdir pat-to-yor-new-folder`
- Open Netbens by clicing to your new short cut and deactivate plugin that you will not use

Windows short cut:
[image: Windows short cut]

Linux short cut:
[image: Linux short cut]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can download [Netbeans archived binaries](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/41/install.html#archives) and store it on different locations on your HD. Latest version:
https://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html
You might also want to read [this](http://ptrthomas.wordpress.com/2008/04/13/never-install-netbeans-again/)

Comment: But there is a promlem. It seems that they do not provide zip distribution after 6.7. Am I right?

Comment: You can get [*6.9*](http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/netbeans/6.9/rc/zip/) as well